# Can't generate new wallet using Ledger Nano S on Mac OS 10.13

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ledger

I've built the 0.12.1 Monero Core release and tried to create the wallet from my Ledger Nano S on device, but get the following error:

```
Error: failed to generate new wallet: Fail SCard API : (-2146435069) Invalid handle. Device=0, hCard=0, hContext=1
```

Things I have done:

- Set up the SmartCard service as much as I could from the instructions from [Ledger Github instructions](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/blue-app-monero/blob/master/doc/user/bolos-app-monero.pdf). I was able to carry out steps 1 to 3 successfully (the file existed for me to ultimately edit). However, note that I am using Mac OS 10.13 and there is no SmartCard installer for 10.13 from the link supplied in the instructions. The [10.12 installer](https://smartcardservices.github.io/installers/) didn't work. Maybe I don't have SmartCard service installed?
- had the Ledger Nano S on Beta 0.12.4 installed.
- had the Monero app active on the Ledger Nano S on before trying to create the wallet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have written a [more descriptive guide to this part of the system configuration](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/how-do-i-make-my-macos-detect-my-ledger-nano-s-when-plugged-in/8439#8439)*

After some help from IRC (thanks selsta), they discovered it was my user error.

In this part of the instructions supplied by Ledger, I didn't add the 2nd string because it already existed and I didn't think I needed to duplicate it. When I did add it, it worked.

```
In <key>ifdVendorID</key> add the entry <string>0x2C97</string>
In <key>ifdProductID</key> add the entry <string>0x0001</string>
In <key>ifdFriendlyName</key> add the entry <string>Ledger Token</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: this error can happen as well when the USB cable is faulty.